# How can I change deprecated HibernateEntityManagerFactory(5.2.10) for add listeners?

Tags: hibernate, listener, factory, deprecated

I try to add listeners to hibernate (5.2.10) entities to get old-new values, after changes. I use SpringBoot and `org.hibernate.HibernateEntityManagerFactory`, but this class marks "Deprecated". 
How could I change my code, to remove deprecated classes?

Now I do something like this:

```
@Component
public class HibernateListenersConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private HibernateEntityListener listener;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {

        // here I see Deprecated warning !!! 
        final HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) this.entityManagerFactory;
        final SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
        final EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE).appendListener(listener);   
    }
```

Comment: Why would you add the listener manually? Isn't `@EntityListeners` working for you? If you need a global entity listener without a common mapped superclass, see here: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event#Default_Entity_Listeners_

Answer (score 0):

You should implement hibernate's [Integrator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator.html#integrate(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration,%20org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor,%20org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry)).

Here's an example: [Hibernate 5 Event Listener Example](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-event-listener-example)